# How to remove special characters like ( ) from url in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, special-characters

I have blog link

```
http://www.example.com/blog/post/somthingin(brackets)
```

I want to remove that brackets in rewrite or by using perl module
How do i do it, please help

Regards,
Santosh